# require.js text plugin adds ".js" to the file name

Tags: javascript, text, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm trying to work with requirejs and text plugin and I have weird problem.

I have two web servers:

1. **localhost:3000** - act as CDN and has all the static files: js, images, css and templates
2. **localhost:3001** - server - act as REST server and serve only one file, the main.html file

The main.html file loads all the **js** files from the second server using the following line:

```
<script data-main="http://localhost:3000/js/main" 
        src="http://localhost:3000/lib/require-jquery.js"></script>
```

For some reason, when using the **requirejs text plugin**, he adds to the templates `".js"` suffix when navigating to **localhost:3001**

I'm using the following syntax:

```
define ['jquery','backbone','underscore','models/model','text!templates/main.html', 
        'views/navigation', 'views/player', 'views/content', 'views/header']
```

when I navigate to **localhost:3000** it works fine.

Can you think of any reason that the text plugin would have problems serving text files from a remote server (for example, CDN server)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've digged in the code of the text plugin.

I've found out that the text plugin assumes that the developer converted the text template to html since it resides on a different domain.

I've change the code of the text plugin to not assume it.

Someone thinks that I'm doing something wrong?

The original code of the plugin:

```
            //Load the text. Use XHR if possible and in a browser.
            if (!hasLocation || useXhr(url, defaultProtocol, defaultHostName, defaultPort)) {
                text.get(url, function (content) {
                    text.finishLoad(name, parsed.strip, content, onLoad, config);
                });
            } else {
                //Need to fetch the resource across domains. Assume
                //the resource has been optimized into a JS module. Fetch
                //by the module name + extension, but do not include the
                //!strip part to avoid file system issues.
                req([nonStripName], function (content) {
                    text.finishLoad(parsed.moduleName + '.' + parsed.ext,
                                    parsed.strip, content, onLoad, config);
                });
            }
```

Comment: Solution has been given by @alex3683

Answer (score 17):

I've had trouble with the text plugin when working across domains and perhaps your two localhost servers are hitting this too.

In the web inspector I saw that **require.js** was trying to fetch things like `some-content.html.js` instead of `some-content.html`.

Are you running this code in development mode or building into a production set?  When you bundle everything up the text plugin shouldn't have this same cross-domain trouble.

Here's the API documentation part that tipped me off (from http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html):

> The baseUrl can be a URL on a different domain as the page that will
>   load require.js. RequireJS script loading works across domains. **The
>   only restriction is on text content loaded by text! plugins: those
>   paths should be on the same domain as the page, at least during
>   development.** The optimization tool will inline text! plugin
>   resources so after using the optimization tool, you can use resources
>   that reference text! plugin resources from another domain.

[Here's an article](http://jaketrent.com/post/cross-domain-requirejs-text/) that helped me work around this for browsers that support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing):

Comment: Whoa, you're right; it's gone. Looks like a parked domain or something now. I have edited it so that it points to an archived version. Note that this answer was written about 4 years ago...so like 40 "web years" ago :)

Answer (score 17):

The [documentation of the text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text#xhr-restrictions) gives a hint to the solution: It's possible to configure the plugin in a way that it always fetches remote resources via XHR without appending the `.js` suffix and loading it via script tag. The simple solution is to always enforce using XHR:

```
requirejs.config({
   config: {
      text: {
         useXhr: function (url, protocol, hostname, port) {
            return true;
         }
      }
   }
});
```

Note that the remote server needs to set the correct CORS header and that this could be a security issue. Thus add the necessary checks for trusted urls when using this instead of simply returning `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I've hacked at every solution I've seen posted on the internet aside from running r.js optimizer and compiling my templates into .js file.

A temporary work around is to put your templates in the same directory as your index.html file.  This of course doesn't solve the problem but if you are at a standstill like I was, then this will at least get you moving again.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem and it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and the fix was to make sure the main.js file was loaded from the same domain as the *.htm files.  When they differed, require would append the .js to the html files, resulting in 404s.

Comment: Still having this problem even though the domain of the main.js file is the same as the templates. Could be a conjunction with the underscore-tpl template plugin

Answer (score 0):

Such config does not work in current text! plugin. My solution was in overriding useXhr  method in 'text' module

```
require(["text"], function (text)
{   if( location.port == '4502' || location.port == '4503' )// AEM env-t
        text.useXhr = function(){ return true; }
    require(["loader/widget/WidgetLoader"]); // dependent on HTML templates by text! plugin
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative way you can use jQuery get method to fetch the content of the template as plain text and then compile it with Handlebars. I came to this solution as a last resort after spending several hours into forums reading about issues with require.js text plugin and CORS. Here's an example :

The template :

```
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">Default</span>
<div class="entry">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="body">
        {{body}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The js script :

```
var deps = [
    'jquery',
    'handlebars',
];

require(deps, function($, handlebars){

    var template = 'https://your_site/raw.templates/basic.handlebars';

    $.get(template, function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
        var Handlebars = handlebars;

        var basicTemplate = Handlebars.compile(data);

        var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"};

        var html = basicTemplate(context);

        var grid = document.createElement('div');
        grid.setAttribute('id', 'itemsGrid');
        grid.innerHTML = html;
        document.body.appendChild(grid);

    });

});
```